# Job Description and requirements being changed after an initial interview

Tags: interviewing, job-search

I recently have been contacted by a company for an interview.

The first contact with the HR was great, then I had a second interview with the manager and some technical guys. I waited for about 8 working days for a reply before sending an email to HR that shows my interest in the job and i asked if there were any news.

They replied saying (paraphrasing):

> They had a positive interview with me and they were happy but they have to change the job description and requirements slightly now though due to changing business needs and they would like me to read to understand if it still fits to my experience and interests.

They said that the manager is in the midst of updating the requirement, but now 5 working days passed but no updates.

I didn't know what they meant, are they telling me in another way that they are not going to accept me? or there was no candidates that fitted the job description? I'm feeling puzzled.

Comment: Voting to close as unclear because the reply you were given seems entirely clear and straight-forward and speculating as to any hidden meaning would be just that - speculating.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I didn't know what they meant, are they telling me in another way that they are not going to accept me? or there was no candidates that fitted the job description?

They are just saying that the job description has changed. In other words, the tasks, responsibilities, charges, etc. the previous position had are to be modified (my guess is that the manager had some sudden change of heart, and had to update his business strategy).

They are asking you to **review the description and requirements again**, so you can see if it is still an option fit for you, giving you the chance to decline in case is something you now don't want to do.

In case you *do* have experience and are willing to take it, then most surely the recruiting process will continue to any other test or screening they may have.

Comment: +1 There's no reason at this point not to take the message at face value, and if they are retooling the position (potentially as part of a wider change or restructure) then that's going to take a while so the delays so far are nothing to worry about IMO